# Reload Tapku Calendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

How can I reload a Tapku calendar?

Here's my situation:
I have a view controller named "Calendar" containing a Tapku a calendar. When the user taps a date, a table view underneath shows the events of that date.

> If the user taps a date, a view controller named "Detail" is pushed onto the navigation stack with info about the event.

On the view controller named "Detail" are options to DELETE this event. If the user deletes the event, the view controller should be pushed off.

> The "Calendar" view shows up again and theoretically, should be made to RELOAD!

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is call [self.monthview reload];

Comment: Same problem for me, where to update  [self.monthview reload];? becoz I'm adding calendar to my own view where there is no monthView in that class.

Answer (score 0):

@iMobileDev You can try this:

```
[self.mTableView reloadData];
```